# <Virtualhost> in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

I have set up virtual host in the config file so that VirtualHost ipaddress:443 ServerName abc.xyz.com

This works so that https://abc.xyz.com works properly but http://abc.xyz.com also works.Is there a way to restrict virtual host so that it's not listen on port 80 for the servername abc.xyz.com?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Change your `Listen` directives in your apache configuration (and optionally specify specific IP addresses and ports in your `VirtualHost` directives).
See [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .I understand listen directive will determine the pots and ip on which the apache webserver wil listem for requests.I have one webserver , 1 ip address and multiple subdomains.so i want to acept connection :443 for one subdomain and reject for :80 on that subdomain,while listening on port 80 for another subdomain.

Comment: @Aditya there is no way I'm aware of to do what you're asking with 1 IP -- If someone hits that IP on port 80 they'll get the site listening on that port.  You could do a NameVirtualHost and redirect the appropriate name to the SSL site, but that's about the best I can come up with...

Comment: One solution i am thinking of involves mod_rewrite and whenever http://abc.xyz.com i redirect to https://abc.xyz.com.By the way like your blog post about bsd and linux .Are you on twitter:).I would like to follow you.